# Euler characteristic of the Mobius band and the Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

It is easy to compute the Euler characteristic of the Mobius band and the Klein bottle using their CW decompositions. However I have an exercise which requires to use the formula $$\chi(X)=\chi(A)+\chi(B)-\chi(C),$$ where X is obtained by gluing two CW complexes $A$ and $B$ along their subcomplex $C$.

I have not any idea how to do that. Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you understand the formula in an inclusion exclusion setting?

Comment: Yes I think it is $\chi(A\cup B)=\chi(A)+\chi(B)-\chi(A\cap B)$...

Comment: Ah so I guess if we glue two copies of the Mobius band along their boundaries to obtain the Klein bottle, then we have $\chi(Klein)=2\chi(Mobius)-\chi(S^1)$. However how can we calculate $\chi(Mobius)$?

Comment: The Möbius band admits a $\Delta$-complex structure. Subdivide the rectangle in triangles until you can glue things properly. Alternatively, the Möbius band deformation retracts onto $S^1$, so they have the same Euler characteristic.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, it is better that you post a solution instead of deleting the post. In this way, other users can benefit from the solution, too.

Comment: Also, the Möbius band can be seen as two rectangles glued together along the disjoint union of two intervals.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above, we can do as follows. Note that the Klein bottle can be obtained by gluing two copies of the Mobius band along their boundaries. Hence by the formula in the question we have $$\chi(Klein)=2\chi(Mobius)-\chi(S^1).$$
Now observe that the Mobius band has the same homotopy type as the circle $S^1$, so they have the same Euler characteristic, which is 0. Therefore, the Euler characteristic of the Klein bottle is also 0.